# How do I get an audio snippet to play when hovering over an image element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio, hover

After too many hours on YT and Google, I'm here. Thanks for taking the time to read & help. :)

I'm trying to make it so that when the mouse hovers over the image, an audio snippet plays automatically. I've tried a few different things, but this is where I stopped.
Can't seem to get anything to work.

HTML file snippet

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>
...other stuff etc etc


<div class="deviruchi" data-tooltip="no touchy!">
<audio id="devi">

    <source src="./sounds/deviruchi_idle.mp3">
    <source src="./sounds/deviruchi_idle.ogg">

</audio>

        <img src="./images/deviruchi.gif">

        </div>
```

Javascript file

```
let deviruchi = $("#devi")[0];
$(".deviruchi").onmouseenter(function () {
    deviruchi.play();
});
```

Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

*Probably because you are using jquery...(j/k, but no really)*

Make sure that the audio files are present on the server, check devtools for error messages (javascript as well as network)
Also, user must first interact with the webpage (click/focus, etc) before browser will allow play media files.

```js
hoverMe.addEventListener("mouseenter", e =>
{
  myAudio.play().catch(er => console.error(er.message, "Now, click here and try again"));
});

hoverMe.addEventListener("mouseleave", e =>
{
  myAudio.pause();
});
```

```html
<div id="hoverMe">Hover over here</div>
<audio id="myAudio" src="https://sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3"></audio>
```